# Major problems since big update/upgrade Ubuntu 2022-04 LTS in July 2023

Tags: updates, 22.04, lts

Big problems occurred after a major automatic update/upgrade in July 2023.
I have a: ASUS TUF DASH F15 gaming laptop with NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3050 Ti Graphic Card 4Gb; Intel core i7-11370H CPU; memory 16 Gb; Clockspeed 3300 Mhz (4800 MHz); 1xTb NVMe PCIe SSD; with Ubuntu 22.04.3 Jammy Jellyfish LTS.

- Shutting down only possible by pushing main button for > 10 seconds
- No more use of second display possible (28" IIYAMA) via HDMI.
- All the NVIDIA-drivers were gone.
- No more entrance as an Admin, because the keyboard don't accept characters as the at-sign @ and the ampersand & in my admin password (this was never an issue). As a normal user I have a simple password and that gives me no entrance to boot from an USB-drive. A USB-keyboard reacts the same as the built in keyboard.

What I have done so far:

- None of the Shift characters above the the numeric characters can be activated when I want to give my admin password, neither on the build-in keyboard nor on the USB-keyboard. All other programs, even here I can produce the @ and the & as it should be.
- Changing the Keyboard-driver did not work.
- All kind of advice's I found on the internet: how I could reset my BIOS Admin password didn't work. It stopped with giving in ALT + R. There was no reaction at all.
- I have a fresh backup from august 15, 2023.
- As a daily user of this laptop I'm stuck. Who can help me.

Thanks for any help,
RobGT,
from the Netherlands

Comment: Did you try booting into the older kernel at GRUB?

Comment: HI,
Thanks for your help.
Replacing the kernel for an older one was a great idea. From a given list I chose v5.15.100 in stead of v6.4.11 That didn't work. Then v5.19.0-50-generic popped, up so I tried that one. Now I've got extra life in my laptop and I can use my 2nd screen again. The laptop shuts down well.
But I still can't use the @ and & for entering the BIOS-utilities. For I want to boot from a USB-stick. In the boot fase of my laptop there seems to be another driver than the standard boot-keyboard-driver. Maybe you have another fabulous idea for solving that problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my keyboard problem in a curious way. I choose another keyboard driver first {Dutch (US)}. When entering the admin password I saw the keyboard didn't accept the @-character and the &-character, though I went on and Entered the password after all and it was accepted.
For now I changed my admin password to a less complicated one.
Now I'm happy being a admin again and being the boss of my own computer again.
The next phase is finding a good driver for my NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3050 Ti Graphic Card. I will put that up in another question.

Thanks for reading my laptop problems.

RobGT, from the Netherlands